# Can Overloaded pre increment and decrement, post increment and decrement operators not work well with inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, operator-overloading, post-increment, pre-increment

Start with the COUNTEN2 program in this chapter. It can increment or decrement a
counter, but only using prefix notation. Using inheritance, add the ability to use postfix
notation for both incrementing and decrementing. (See Chapter 8 for a description of
postfix notation.)

I was trying to solve this exercise from robert lafore OOPv4 book and when I inherited a class that had pre-increment and decrement and tried to add post-increment and decrement in its derived class it showed this error
main.cpp:55:5: error: no match for ‘operator++’ (operand type is ‘CountP’)
when I remove either pre or post increment it works fine but gives an error otherwise. I am an absolute beginner so help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
class Counter{
 protected:
    unsigned int count;
 public:
    Counter() : count(){ 
        
    }
    Counter(int c) : count(c){
        
    }
    void display(){
        cout<<count<<endl;
    }
    Counter operator ++ (){  //   Pre increment operator
        return Counter(++count); 
    }
 };

class CountDn : public Counter{
 public:
    CountDn() : Counter(){
        
    }
    CountDn(int c) : Counter(c){
        
    }
    CountDn operator -- (){ 
        return CountDn(--count); 
    }
 };
class CountP : public CountDn{
 public:
    CountP() : CountDn(){
        
    }
    CountP(int c) : CountDn(c){
        
    }
     
    CountP operator ++(int){ //   Post increment operator
        return CountP(count++);
    }
    CountP operator --(int){
        return CountP(count--);
    }
 };
int main()
{    
CountP cp1(5),cp2;
CountDn cd1(7);
++cp1;
cp1.display();
cp1;
cp1.display();
cp1++;
cp1.display();
return 0;
}
```